# change inputText via ref

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm going to change the textinput via ref, but nothing happens

My code in the render is as follows

```
<TextInput
       onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({replyTicketText: value})} />
       ref={"replyInput"+this.state.ticketID}
       />
```

When I call the function:

```
let replyInput;
          replyInput = "replyInput"+this.state.ticketID;
          this.refs[replyInput].setNativeProps({ text: ' ' });
```

platfrom: ios

Comment: It's unclear what are you trying to do.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I have several inputText and I want to clear them through the ref. What solution do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably misunderstanding, but would it not be easier to hook the input to state, the field will update when state is changed?

value={this.state.replyTicketText}

Comment: thanks, I tried this solution and did not work on ios, I have several inputText and I want to clear them through the ref. What solution do you recommend?

Comment: Maybe an array structure in state, link each of the inputs to each of those and clear the array element in state instead?